The send command in a sh script is not executed
I'm new to linux, so the question will seem idiotic, but still. How to solve the problem with the send command not being executed after the terminal asks for a password, please help. (The script tries to run all files with ovpn extension in the directory to connect via openvpn protocol to the server and disconnects after successful connection). The login is entered, but the password is not entered and the script stops executing.
Here is the code of the main program:
#!/bin/bash

cd /etc/openvpn || { echo "Failed to navigate to this directory"; exit 1; }

CRED="/home/noname/Desktop/cred.txt"

if [[! -f "$CRED"]]; then
    echo "File not found"
    exit 1
fi

for ov in *.ovpn; do
    echo "Connecting to $ov ..."
    sudo ./ex.sh "$ov" &
        vpn_pid=$!
    
    sleep 15
    
    if ps -p $vpn_pid > /dev/null; then
        echo "Connection succesfull with $ov"
        exit 0
    else
        echo  "Connection failed with $ov"
    fi
    sudo kill $vpn_pid 2>/dev/null
done

echo "Operation complete"

Here is the script code:
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout 20


set username "..."
set password "..."


set ovpn_file [lindex $argv 0]


spawn sudo openvpn $ovpn_file


expect "Enter Auth Username:" { send "$username\r" }
sleep 2
send -- "$password\r"

interact

I also tried using send without the -- flag. but it still fails to execute.
I also tried not to use a separate script, but in this case I should have used the flag when calling sudo openvpn --auth-user-pass, but for some reason the program does not run with this flag.  - If you can solve this problem, you probably won't have to solve the problem with the send command, it's up to you, сonsidering what's easier for you.

Please paste your script at shellcheck.net and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Run the script with sudo instead.  sudo ./script.sh
